# How does one solve $\lim_{n\to\infty} \int_0^\infty \frac{\sin(x/n)}{x+x^2}dx$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, improper-integrals, lebesgue-integral

I believe this converges point wise but I am not sure how to evaluate $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \int_0^\infty \frac{\sin(x/n)}{x+x^2}dx.$$ Can someone please help?

Comment: For the integral from $0$ to $1$ use: $\sin t <t$. For the integral from $1$ to $\infty$ use DCT with dominating function $\frac  1{x^{2}}$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Thank you, can you please expound a bit further. I understand the first part, but with DCT, why do we chose $\frac{1}{x^2}$?

Comment: Numerator is bounded by $1$. Denominator is $\geq x^{2}$. And $\int_1^{\infty} \frac  1 {x^{2}}=1<\infty$.

Comment: Oh so its actually easier than I thought, wow @KaviRamaMurthy thanks!

Comment: Hint: $$ \begin{align} \int_0^\infty\left|\frac{\sin(x/n)}{x+x^2}\right|\mathrm{d}x &=\int_0^\infty\left|\frac{\sin(x)}{x+nx^2}\right|\mathrm{d}x\\ &=\int_0^1\left|\frac{\sin(x)}{x+nx^2}\right|\mathrm{d}x+\int_1^\infty\left|\frac{\sin(x)}{x+nx^2}\right|\mathrm{d}x \end{align} $$

Answer (score 3):

So maybe this is another example of tricking the integral to allow the limit inside itself. We can do this in a lot of ways, but I'm very fond of leveraging dominated convergence theorem. Observe, for any $n,$ we see:
$$\int_0^{\infty} \frac{\sin(x/n)}{x + x^2} dx = \underbrace{\int_0^{\epsilon} \frac{\sin(x/n)}{x + x^2} dx}_{I} + \underbrace{\int_{\epsilon}^{\infty}  \frac{\sin(x/n)}{x + x^2} dx}_{II}$$

Consider the first integral. We know within an $\epsilon$-ball of the origin, we see:
$$\sin(x/n) = \frac{x}{n} + \frac{x^3}{3! n^3 } + \ldots $$
we can then evaluate
$$\int_0^{\epsilon} \frac{\sin(x/n)}{x + x^2} dx = \int_0^{\epsilon} \frac{\frac{x}{n} + \frac{x^3}{3! n^3 } + \ldots}{x + x^2} dx = \int_0^{\epsilon} \frac{\frac{1}{n} + \frac{x^2}{3! n^3}}{1 + x^2} dx \leq \frac{\epsilon}{n}$$
Clearly, as $n \rightarrow \infty,$ the integral decays to zero. So $I \rightarrow 0.$ Now consider the other integral.

$$II = \int_{\epsilon}^{\infty}  \frac{\sin(x/n)}{x + x^2} dx$$

Clearly $\left | \frac{\sin(x/n)}{x + x^2}\right| \leq \frac{1}{x+x^2} $ for all choices of $n$. Further, we know
$$\int_{\epsilon}^{\infty}  \frac{1}{x + x^2} dx < \infty$$
Therefore, by the dominated convergence theorem, we know $II$ converges. Since both converge uniformly, then we can see:
$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} II =\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_{\epsilon}^{\infty}  \frac{\sin(x/n)}{x + x^2} dx = \int_{\epsilon}^{\infty} \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}  \frac{\sin(x/n)}{x + x^2} dx =  \int_{\epsilon}^{\infty}  0 \ dx = 0$$

Therefore,
$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_{0}^{\infty}  \frac{\sin(x/n)}{x + x^2} dx =\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} I + II = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{\epsilon}{n} + 0 = 0$$

Comment: It should be $-\frac{x^3}{3!n^3}$.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is:
$$L=\lim_{x\to 0}\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sin(x/n)}{x+x^2}$$
if we look at:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sin(x/n)}{x+x^2}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{-x\cos(x/n)}{x(x+1)n^2}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{-\cos(x/n)}{(x+1)n^2}=-\frac{1}{x+1}$$
and so:
$$L=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{-1}{x+1}=-1$$
so the integrand converges to a finite value for $x=0$ now if we look at the integral:
$$\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin(x/n)}{x+x^2}dx<\int_0^\infty\frac{x/n}{x+x^2}dx=\lim_{h\to\infty}\frac1n\int_0^h\frac{1}{1+x}dx$$
and so our integral, $I$, satisfies:
$$I\le\lim_{(n,h)\to(\infty,\infty)}\frac{\ln(1+h)}{n}=0$$

Answer (score 1):

*Since you received good answers for the limit, let me go beyond it.*

Let $x=n t$
$$I=\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin \left(\frac{x}{n}\right)}{x^2+x}dx=\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin (t)}{n t^2+t} dt=\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin (t)}{t} dt-\frac 1n\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin (t)}{t+\frac1n} dt$$

$$\sin(t)=\sin \left(t+\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n}\right)=\sin \left(t+\frac{1}{n}\right)\cos\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)-\cos \left(t+\frac{1}{n}\right)\sin\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)$$ So, for tha last integral, there is an obvious change of variable and we face classic integrals.

Back to $x$, the antiderivative
$$J=\int\frac{\sin \left(\frac{x}{n}\right)}{x^2+x}dx=\sin \left(\frac{1}{n}\right)
   \text{Ci}\left(\frac{x+1}{n}\right)+\text{Si}\left(\frac{x}{n}\right)-\cos
   \left(\frac{1}{n}\right) \text{Si}\left(\frac{x+1}{n}\right)$$ and
$$I=\frac{\pi}{2}   \left(1-\cos \left(\frac{1}{n}\right)\right)+\text{Si}\left(\frac{1}{n}\right) \cos
   \left(\frac{1}{n}\right)-\text{Ci}\left(\frac{1}{n}\right) \sin
   \left(\frac{1}{n}\right)$$

Using the asymptotics of the sine and cosines integrals
$$I=\frac{\log \left(n\right)+1-\gamma }{n}+\frac{\pi }{4
   n^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right)$$